# nginx and supervisor setup in Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx, supervisord

I'm using django-gunicorn-nginx setup by following this tutorial http://ijcdigital.com/blog/django-gunicorn-and-nginx-setup/ Upto nginx setup, it is working. Then I installed supervisor, configured it and then I reboot my server and checked, it shows 502 bad gateway. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/qlimp.conf

```
[program: qlimp]
directory = /home/nirmal/project/qlimp/qlimp.sh
user = nirmal
command = /home/nirmal/project/qlimp/qlimp.sh
stdout_logfile = /path/to/supervisor/log/file/logfile.log
stderr_logfile = /path/to/supervisor/log/file/error-logfile.log
```

Then I restarted supervisor and I run this command `$ supervisorctl start qlimp` and I'm getting this error

```
unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file
```

Is there any problem in my supervisor setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 66):

That there is no socket file probably means that supervisor isn't running. A reason that it isn't running might be that your qlimp.conf file has some sort of error in it. If you do a

```
sudo service supervisor start
```

you can see whether or not this is the case. If supervisor is already running, it will say. And if it is catching an error, it will usually give you a more helpful error message than supervisorctl.

Comment: I got the same error. Your command fixed it. How to I debug the error in qlimp.conf file?

Comment: When I run this I get `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log'`

Comment: Turns out that I had a non-root user specified under `[supervisord]`

Comment: hi @nueverest how you resolve the permission denied?

Comment: @sulaiman make sure that you look at your `conf` file under [supervisord] the user specified there must have root access.

Answer (score 27):

I have met the same issue as you and after several times, here comes the solution:

1. First remove the apt-get supervisor version:

   ```
     sudo apt-get remove supervisor
   ```
2. Kill the backend supervisor process:

   ```
    sudo ps -ef | grep supervisor
   ```
3. Then get the newest version(apt-get version was 3.0a8):

   ```
   sudo easy_install(pip install) supervisor==3.0b2
   ```
4. Echo the config file(root premission):

   ```
   echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf
   ```

5.Start supervisord:

```
   sudo supervisord
```

6.Enter supervisorctl:

```
   sudo supervisorctl
```

Anything has been done! Have fun!

Comment: When I run `sudo echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf` I get `Permission Denied`

Comment: @nu everest So you must run as a super administrator instead.

Comment: So you must run as a super administrator instead. STILL NOT WORKING, ANY OTHER SUGGESTIONS? @Scen

Answer (score 18):

Try this

```
cd /etc/supervisor
sudo supervisord
sudo supervisorctl restart all
```

Comment: This worked for me because supervisor is not installed as a service on my server. I need to manually start it after a reboot with `supervisord` before I can use `supervisorctl`. Thank you Anil

Comment: Worked for me, I have this running inside docker and the sock file looks like it was not created at start, even though supervisord was up in the ps list. "sudo supervisord" seems to kick it to create it, though it threw an warning message that I was running it as root

Answer (score 12):

Are you sure that supervisord is installed and running? Is there a socket file in present at `/var/run/supervisor.sock`?

The error indicates that `supervisorctl`, the control CLI, cannot reach the UNIX socket to communicate with `supervisord`, the daemon.

You could also check `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` and see if the values for the `unix_http_server` and `supervisorctl` sections match.

Note that this is a Ubuntu-level problem, not a problem with Python, Django or nginx and as such this question probably belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: No. there is no supervisor.sock file in /var/run Why is it so?

Comment: If `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`, section `unix_http_server` has a file entry pointing to `/var/run/supervisor.sock`, then supervisord is not running or installed. Run `sudo /etc/init.d/supervisor start` to see if it'll start.

Comment: I tried running `sudo /etc/init.d/supervisor start` and I got error in `path/to` is not found. Then I changed to `/etc/supervisor/log/` Now I got the supervisor.sock file..rebooted and then checked. Still getting **502 bad gateway**

Comment: Right, now you have either an nginx configuration problem or your upstream is not running. Try accessing localhost:8001 directly.

Answer (score 10):

On Ubuntu 16+ it seems to been caused by the switch to systemd, this workaround may fix for new servers:

```
 # Make sure Supervisor comes up after a reboot.
 $ sudo systemctl enable supervisor

 # Bring Supervisor up right now.
 $ sudo systemctl start supervisor
```

and then do check your status of **iconic.conf [My example]** of supervisor

```
$ sudo supervisorctl status iconic
```

[image]

PS: Make sure gunicorn should not have any problem while running.

Answer (score 5):

The error may be due to that you don't have the privilege.
Maybe you can fix the error by this way, open your terminal, and input `vim /etc/supervisord.conf` to edit the file, search the lines

```
[unix_http_server]
;file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
;chmod=0700                  ; socket file mode (default 0700)
```

and delete the Semicolon in the start of the string `;file=/tmp/supervisor.sock` and `;chmod=0700`, restart your supervisord. I suggest you do it.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that in `/etc/supervisor.conf` the following two sections exists

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock ; path to your socket file

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
```

Comment: what is the path to socket file?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :-

```
sudo touch /var/run/supervisor.sock
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/supervisor.sock
sudo service supervisor restart
```

It's definitely work, try this.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Supervisor was not running. To spot the issue I run:

```
sudo systemctl status supervisor.service
```

The problem was that I had my logs pointing to a non-existing directory, so I just had to create it.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks! That solved it for me. Actually, supervisor.conf was okay, but a service file in the `conf.d` folder pointed to a non-existing directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
touch /var/run/supervisor.sock
sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

and after
    supervisorctl restart all

if you want to listen the supervisor port

```
ps -ef | grep supervisord
```

if you want kill the process

```
kill -s SIGTERM 2503
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a conf file and below add lines

Remember that in order to work with Nginx, you must have to disable autostart on system boot, that you activated while installing Nginx.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/177041/nginx-disable-autostart

**Note: All the supervisor processes must be on "daemon off" mode, in order to work with supervisor**

```
[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=5
stopasgroup=true
stopsignal=QUIT
numprocs=1
startsecs=0
process_name=WebServer(Nginx)
stderr_logfile=/var/log/nginx/error.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/access.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
```

`sudo supervisorctl reread && sudo supervisorctl update`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this error several times -

### **If server is newly created instance and facing this issue**

Might be because of some wrong config or mistake happened during the process, or supervisor is not enabled.

1. Try restarting your supervisor and reconnecting ec2

   or
2. Try reinstalling supervisor (@Scen)

   or
3. Try approaches mentioned by @Yuvaraj Loganathan, @Dinesh Sunny. But mostly you might end up creating a new instance.

### If server was running perfectly from long time but then it suddenly stopped

and threw
`unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file` on `sudo supervisorctl status`.

It may be due to high memory usage, refer below image usage was 99% of 7.69GB earlier.

[image]

1. You can find the above config after connecting with ec2 via `ssh` or `putty` at the top.
2. You can upgrade your ec2 instance or you can then delete any extra files like logs (/var/logs), zip to free up the space. **But careful do not delete any system files**.
3. Restart supervisor
   `sudo service supervisor restart`
4. Check `sudo supervisorctl status`